# Events in FullCalendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

Hello 
I am showing events using the Month View with the [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) plugin.

When a day has more than 3/4 events scheduled the day cell increase it's height to show all the events and the resulting render is not so user friendly as you would.

Is there a way to modify that cell rendering so for example it would show just a couple of events and then a "More..." hyperlink that jumps to a more appropriate [DayView](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/)?

Answer (score 0):

if you know a server side language like php you can limit the output to 4 max ouput and display a more link if more than 4 exists and link them to the day view. i would write it out for you but i am new to it myself.